# Utf8Json: <Type> is not registered in this resolver(EnumUnderlyingValueResolver). An exception occurs while serializing an enum as number

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, enums, utf8json

I am trying to serialize a c# object with an enum property to JSON using [utf8json](/questions/tagged/utf8json) and format its enum values as numbers using `EnumResolver.UnderlyingValue`, however when I do so an exception is thrown.  How can I prevent this exception?

I have these classes below:

```
[DataContract]
public class Physics
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Lecturer { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public WeekDays WeekDay { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public enum WeekDays : byte
{
    [EnumMember]
    Monday = 1,

    [EnumMember]
    Tuesday,

    [EnumMember]
    Wednesday,

    [EnumMember]
    Thursday,

    [EnumMember]
    Friday,

    [EnumMember]
    Saturday,

    [EnumMember]
    Sunday
}
```

Here is my Main() method.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Physics physics_1 = new Physics { Lecturer = "Andrew", WeekDay = WeekDays.Monday };
    var v1 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(physics_1, EnumResolver.UnderlyingValue);
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(v1));
}
```

I want to serialize a Physics object and also I want the enum member of Physics to be serialized as a number.  But upon using `EnumResolver.UnderlyingValue` I got an exception *Physics is not registered in this resolver*:

> ```
> Utf8Json.FormatterNotRegisteredException: Physics is not registered in this resolver. resolver:EnumUnderlyingValueResolver
>    at Utf8Json.JsonFormatterResolverExtensions.GetFormatterWithVerify[T](IJsonFormatterResolver resolver)
>    at Utf8Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize[T](T value, IJsonFormatterResolver resolver)
> ```

How can I serialize my object as required?

Answer (score 1):

[`EnumResolver.UnderlyingValue`](https://github.com/neuecc/Utf8Json/blob/master/src/Utf8Json/Resolvers/EnumResolver.cs#L17) only resolves formatters for `Enum` objects.  In order to resolve formatters for other types you must combine it with a [standard resolver](https://github.com/neuecc/Utf8Json/blob/master/src/Utf8Json/Resolvers/StandardResolver.cs) using [`CompositeResolver`](https://github.com/neuecc/Utf8Json/blob/master/src/Utf8Json/Resolvers/CompositeResolver.cs) e.g. like so:

```
public static class Utf8JsonConfiguration
{
    static public IJsonFormatterResolver Resolver { get; } = 
        CompositeResolver.Create(EnumResolver.UnderlyingValue, StandardResolver.Default);
}
```

And then later do:

```
var physics_1 = new Physics { Lecturer = "Andrew", WeekDay = WeekDays.Monday };
var v1 = JsonSerializer.Serialize(physics_1, Utf8JsonConfiguration.Resolver);
```

Which results in `{"Lecturer":"Andrew","WeekDay":1}` as required.

This is explained in more detail on the documentation page [Utf8Json - Fast JSON Serializer for C#: Resolver](https://github.com/neuecc/Utf8Json#resolver).

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GHwRCo).